# How to grep multiple strings when using with another command?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pipe

I am trying to find out how I can use:

```
grep -i
```

With multiple strings, after using grep on another command. For example:

```
last | grep -i abc
last | grep -i uyx
```

I wish the combine the above into one command, but when searching on the internet I can only find references on how to use multiple strings with grep, when grep is used with a file, and not a command. I have tried something like this:

```
last | grep -i (abc|uyx)
```

Or

```
last | grep -i 'abc|uyx'
```

But that doesn't work. What is the correct syntax to get the results I epxect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I can only find references on how to use multiple strings with grep, when grep is used with a file, and not a command" - it does not matter where the input for `grep` comes from, be it a file or a command. The options are still the same.

Comment: Or to make it more clear: `last | grep -i -e abc -e xyz`

Comment: ... `grep -i 'abc|uyx'` doesn't work because `|` is not an alternation operator in basic regular expression (BRE); you'd need `grep -Ei 'abc|uyx'` (`-E` for **e**xtended regular expression mode)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Many options with `grep` alone, starting with the standard ones:

```
grep -i -e abc -e uyx
grep -i 'abc
uyx'
grep -i -E 'abc|uyx'
```

With some `grep` implementations, you can also do:

```
grep -i -P 'abc|uyx' # perl-like regexps, sometimes also with
                     # --perl-regexp or -X perl
grep -i -X 'abc|uyx' # augmented regexps (with ast-open grep) also with
                     # --augmented-regexp
grep -i -K 'abc|uyx' # ksh regexps (with ast-open grep) also with
                     # --ksh-regexp
grep -i 'abc\|uyx'   # with the \| extension to basic regexps supported by
                     # some grep implementations. BREs are the
                     # default but with some grep implementations, you
                     # can make it explicit with -G, --basic-regexp or
                     # -X basic
```

You can add `(...)`s around `abc|uyx` (`\(...\)` for BREs), but that's not necessary. The `(`s and `)`s, like `|` also need to be quoted for them to be passed literally to `grep` as they are special characters in the syntax of the shell language.

Case insensitive matching can also be enabled as part of the regexp syntax with some `grep` implementations (not standardly).

```
grep -P '(?i)abc|uyx' # wherever -P / --perl-regexp / -X perl is supported
grep -K '~(i)abc|uyx' # ast-open grep only
grep -E '(?i)abc|uyx' # ast-open grep only
grep '\(?i\)abc|uyx'  # ast-open grep only which makes it non-POSIX-compliant
```

Those don't really bring much advantage over the standard `-i` option. Where it could be more interesting would be for instance if you want `abc` matching to be case sensitive and `uyx` not, which you could do with:

```
grep -P 'abc|(?i)uyx'
```

Or:

```
grep -P 'abc|(?i:uyx)'
```

(and equivalent variants with other regexp syntaxes).

The standard equivalent of that would look like:

```
grep -e abc -e '[uU][yY][xX]'
```

(bearing in mind that case-insensitive matching is often locale-dependent; for instance, whether uppercase `i` is `I` or `İ` may depend on the locale according to `grep -i i`).

Answer (score 2):

```
grep 'abc\|uyx'
egrep 'abc|uyx'
```